# JavaScript - opposite of toString()?

Tags: javascript, tostring

When used with numbers, the toString() method converts a number into a string representation using the base numbering system specified by the optional radix.

For instance the number 8 and toString(2) would return "1000".

Is there a method to achieve the opposite? I.e., convert the string "1000" back into the number 8?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`parseInt()` takes a radix as its second argument, so you can do `parseInt("1000", 2)` to get what you want.

Comment: @AlexStack Number.prototype.toString(radix)

Answer (score 10):

You can use parseInt using a raidx 2.
i.e

```
parseInt("1000", 2) will return 8
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the parseInt() Javascript function:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp